# How can I use mutt execute command tag-pattern and then delete-pattern via shell?

Tags: mutt

Is there a way to execute `mutt`'s `tag-pattern` and then `delete-pattern` via shell?

```
  -e <command>  specify a command to be executed after initialization
```

Could someone provide an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example:

Suppose you want to delete and purge messages from the `testmbox` mailbox, containing [DELETE-ME] in the subject line.

You can do this:

`mutt -f testmbox -e "push <tag-pattern>~s[DELETE-ME]\n<tag-prefix><delete-message><sync-mailbox>\n"`

This works because:

- -e executes configuration commands
- 'push' is a configuration command that add key sequences to the keyboard buffer, i.e. to mutt, looks just like entering `T~s[DELETE-ME]<ENTER>;d$<ENTER>` interactively (assuming a default keyboard layout).

*Tested with mutt 1.5.21*

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way get this to work via `cron` (no `tty`)?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use

```
<delete-pattern>
```

instead of

```
<tag-pattern>
```

, because when no pattern is matching, the

```
<delete-message>
```

would delete the first message in the list, even if is not matching the desired pattern.